# How to fix this error: `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}`

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication, jwt

I have tried many things to solve my problem but I can't resolve it.
I want to give user details when I give the token but I get this error: ##AssertionError at /api/token/get
`HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.##

Here the code in views.py

```py
class GetUserInfo(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    # permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user)
        # serializer to handle turning our `User` object into something that
        # can be JSONified and sent to the client.


        return Response({"user": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here the code in serializers.py

```py
lass UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('title', 'dob', 'address', 'country', 'city', 'zip', 'photo','director','manager','collaborator')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        profile = instance.profile

        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.save()

        profile.title = profile_data.get('title', profile.title)
        profile.dob = profile_data.get('dob', profile.dob)
        profile.address = profile_data.get('address', profile.address)
        profile.country = profile_data.get('country', profile.country)
        profile.city = profile_data.get('city', profile.city)
        profile.zip = profile_data.get('zip', profile.zip)
        profile.photo = profile_data.get('photo', profile.photo)
        director = profile_data.get('director', profile.director)
        manager = profile_data.get('manager', profile.manager)
        collaborator = profile_data.get('collaborator', profile.collaborator)
        profile.save()
```

My urls.py

````py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('token/get', GetUserInfo.as_view()),
   ...
]```

In complement, I show my model:
```python
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True,max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1} ({2})".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email)

class Company (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

""" 
User's detail
"""
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    dob = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', blank=True)
    director =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manager =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    collaborator =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='compnay')
````

Could you help me to fix this error and get my Json please ?

Comment: Have you tried what the error is saying? `serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user, context={'request': request})`

Comment: sounds very simple when I read that haha ! Thank you very much it works perfectly.